# I'm closing my writestreams but I get Error: EMFILE: too many open files

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, fs, createwritestream

I'm using NodeJS and the fs module and I'm getting Error: EMFILE: too many open files when using writestreams.

The thing is that I'm actually closing them so what 's going on?

Comment: No code, no help. Your are a member for 1+ and didnt even completed the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Sorry, it's just my code is extremely specific. In a nutshell I'm downloading about 60,000 images and [here is my download function](https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/axozolotoc.js). I included another couple things there just in case they're useful. I'm using that function in another async function and I'm awaiting it so that my for loop pauses between executions. If you need any more information then let me know!